# Advice regarding DB design for DB with varying/dynamic number of fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a drug information web application using PHP/MySQL. I do not know how do deal with the need for varying numbers of fields. For example, side effects. One drug may have three side effects, and another 30. I have thought of two potential solutions, both seem awful:

1. Have 30 columns, e.g. side_effect_1, side_effect_2, etc., and have a lot of null values in those columns for most drugs.
2. List all the side effects in one column, comma delimited, and then figure out how to deal with that (I guess as some sort of nested array? Wouldn't that end up being an array within the array of whatever query PHP is sending?)

I'm a newbie, but I swear I've spent hours trying to find solutions online, to no avail. There does seem to be a sentiment out there that this issue (dynamic number of fields) may be best handled by a NoSQL database. Though most of my fields will have nice, neat, one-to-one relationships, there are a handful (side effects, indications, contraindications) that will vary wildly in their number. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about mysql JSON data type or use NOSQL?

Comment: Consider that side-effects are re-usable. Create a medication table with an id for each medication. Create a side-effects table with id's for each side-effect. Then have an intermediate table where each row has the medication's id in one column and a side-effect's id in another. Now you can use JOIN's to get all of the medication's side-effects and you have re-usable side-effects.No need for dynamic fields at all.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get around the problem that one medication may have five side effects, and another 12? Whether I'm actually listing the side effect or a side effect ID (that correlates to the side effect in a joined table), I'm still needing a varying number of columns fields, right?

Comment: No. You will select all of the rows from the intermediate table (see the answer below) which correlates to 'this' medication's side-effects. Another medication will JOIN all of the rows for its id and so on. Let's say side-effect id 1 is headache and 2 is nausea. Medication 1 has only has headache (medication id 1 and side-effect id 1) while Medication 2 has both (2, 1 and 2, 2). We have a row in the intermediate table for each side-effect connected to a medication.

Comment: Thank you. This helps immensely.

Comment: Here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d00452/11

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with two distinct kinds of data here. On the one hand you have the drugs, and on the other the side effects. This directly gives you the answer to the question: you need two tables. Now to connect those two you need another that takes care of doing exactly that.

```
┌───────┐    ┌───────────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ drugs │    │ drug_side_effects │    │ side_effects │
├───────┤    ├───────────────────┤    ├──────────────┤
│ id    │    │ drug_id           │    │ id           │
│ name  │    │ side_effect_id    │    │ name         │
└───────┘    └───────────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

Not only can you have *n* side effects per drug now, you can also ensure referential integrity and avoid duplicates (or more) in your storage.

Comment: So this is a many-to-many? And in the side_effects table I will have _n_ number of rows for each side effect?

Comment: Each side-effect in the side_effects table gets one row (same for drugs - each drug gets one row). The drug_side_effects table will be your many to many table.

Comment: @jaylblanchard Okay, I see (I think). Thanks!

Comment: You can look at this http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/img/manymany-links-img.html from this http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php to get another explanation that is more verbose. Happy learning. :)